# Bootstrap element not hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I wanna hidden search box in Small Devices(sm) size and instead of that a search button should take place. i wanna my search be like this at sm size.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7U8v.jpg)

this is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <img src="img/1.png" class="header-logo" alt="site-logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group search-box">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 btn-header">
                    <button class="btn">ورود</button>
                    <button class="btn">ثبت نام</button>
                </div>
            </div>

</div><!-- =====HEADER DIV===== -->
    </div>
```

Comment: if you use font awosome:  you have to fix `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>` **to**   `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show or hide elements with bootstrap you have to use the display utilities. For example, if you want to show only on Small Devices you must use `d-none d-block d-sm-none`.

Your code would be like this:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <img src="img/1.png" class="header-logo" alt="site-logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-md-block">
                    <div class="input-group search-box">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 btn-header d-sm-none">
                    <button class="btn">ورود</button>
                    <button class="btn">ثبت نام</button>
                </div>
            </div>

</div><!-- =====HEADER DIV===== -->
    </div>
```

You can find the doc here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: tnx it WORKS!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

> hidden-sm

for more details follow https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

```
            <div class="input-group search-box">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- your search field is hidden in the sm -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control hidden-sm" placeholder="جستجو">
                </div>
```

**Devices list**

- Extra small devices - Phones (<768px)
- Small devices - Tablets (≥768px)
- Medium devices -Desktops (≥992px)
- Large devices -Desktops (≥1200px)

Comment: its now working.... i shrink size of the browser and its not working. it there all the time.

Comment: You want to hide .btn-header section when device is SM ?

Comment: i wanna hide search box when devise is SM

Comment: I have edited the code. please check, now button is hidden when device is sm, you should have to write js code to show the search box as you need, you can use  $('.fas.fa-search').slideToggle() like jquery code